# Howto get better icon for WhatsApp when installed on Windows 11?

Tags: windows-11

WhatsApp Desktop can only be installed from Microsoft Store, however its icon looks like it was designed for Windows 95:

[image]

To be clear, I wish that blue background to be transparent.

Where is this icon exactly? I couldn't find it in `C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\...`.

Comment: Use Resource Hacker     https://www.howtogeek.com/75983/stupid-geek-tricks-how-to-modify-the-icon-of-an-.exe-file/#:~:text=In%20the%20Resource%20Hacker%20window,icon%20you%20want%20to%20use.

Comment: How can I check where is this application's exe file path?

Comment: Assuming you got Resource Hacker installed, look for .MUI files  .   Here is one place.     ......  C:\Windows\System32\es-ES

Answer (score 1):

Changing the icon of a Microsoft Store app is more complicated than for
a desktop application, but a workaround is found in the post
[change the taskbar icon for windows store apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70413031/change-the-taskbar-icon-for-windows-store-apps).

Below is the
[anser by Magnarokk](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70507827/165358),
which was verified by the poster :

> Start by creating this script with any name (for example AppIdScript),
> just make sure the extension is .ps1
>
> ```
> $installedapps = get-AppxPackage
>
>
> foreach ($app in $installedapps)
> {
>     foreach ($id in (Get-AppxPackageManifest $app).package.applications.application.id)
>     {
>
>         $line = $app.Name + " = " + $app.packagefamilyname + "!" + $id
>         echo $line
>
>     }
> }
> Start-Sleep
> ```
>
> Then save, right click and run with powershell.
>
> You can also run this command in a command prompt, the results are
> similar.
>
> ```
> reg query HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\ /s /f AppUserModelID | find "REG_SZ"
> ```

(Note : The above command never finishes, so has to be terminated
by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.)

> Next copy the output of the script to a txt file (so you can Ctrl+F
> and search for app names in it).
>
> Once you've found the app you want to change the icon for, copy its
> App ID (usually starting with "Microsoft."), then right click on your
> desktop, create new shortcut, and paste in
>
> ```
> explorer.exe shell:appsFolder\PasteAppIDHere
> ```
>
> and click Next.
>
> Now you have a shortcut with the File Explorer icon, so right click
> and go to properties, click Change Icon..., and select the .ico file
> you want to replace it with. Apply the changes and click OK.
>
> Once that's done, open a new command prompt window, drag and drop in
> the "Win7AppId1.1.exe" file (if you no longer have it here's the
> download [link](https://storage.googleapis.com/google-code-archive-downloads/v2/code.google.com/win7appid/Win7AppId1.1.exe)) into the prompt, then press space, then drag in
> the shortcut you just created, the press space, then paste the App ID,
> then press enter.
>
> For example the creation of the shortcut for the Xbox App looked like
> this for me:
>
> ```
> "C:\Users\MYNAME\Desktop\Win7AppId1.1.exe" C:\Users\MYNAME\Desktop\Xbox.lnk
> ```
>
> Microsoft.GamingApp_8wekyb3d8bbwe!Microsoft.Xbox.App
>
> Once you're done, you should be able to put the shortcut on your
> taskbar and the icon should stay the same.